# tfignore file not ignoring files with asp.net 5 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, azure-devops

While working with ASP.NET 5 projects using TFVC and Visual Studio 2015, we have noticed that adding a .tfignore file that tries to exclude folders and files in the wwwroot directory are still showing up in Team Explorer as Pending Changes. Since the CSS and JavaScript files don't need to be checked in (they are being generated from SASS and TypeScript sources) we would like them excluded. We have added a simple .tfignore file to our project that just has an entry of \wwwroot (we figured we would start by making it as simple as possible and just ignoring everything in the wwwroot directory) and the file does not seem to be recognized since items in the wwwroot folder still show up in our Pending Changes window. We have also tried to follow the steps listed at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx#tfignore under the "Create and use a .tfignore file" section and while that added entries to a global .tfignore file, the directory that should have been excluded was still showing up in Pending Changes. Is the .tfignore file supposed to work with ASP.NET 5 projects? When searching for a solution, I came across articles talking about the .tfignore file not excluding things from Solution Explorer (which I would not expect to be how things worked), but nothing seemed to mention anything around TFVC and the .tfignore.

We are working with a Local Workspace in TFVC and have not ever checked in files for the wwwroot directory (we are all manually making sure to exclude them when doing checkins, but would be nice if it would happen automatically with .tfignore file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with ASP.NET5, please refer to this link for details: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/18

Comment: I actually had seen that github issue, but it seemed like it was trying to kill two birds with one stone and so the work being done on that issue wasn't very clear to me. The title explicitly mentioned the issue relating to "items still being shown in Solution Explorer" and all the conversation seemed to be around showing and hiding files from Solution Explorer (which I don't believe tfignore should handle) and didn't seem to be talking about source code control much. After looking at the thread closer, I see towards the bottom they bring it back to source control. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a workaround we can use until VS2015 Update 3 is released?

Comment: FWIW, we're still having that issue with VS 2015 Update 3